# Do I need to repeat on the word "word" in the following sentence?

Tags: adjectives

Do I need to repeat on the word "word" in the following sentence?

> "The word “lumbar” came from Latin ***word*** “lumbus” that means loin. "

Comment: Here's how I'd write the sentence: *The word "lumbar" came from Latin "lumbus," which means "loin."* I'm not sure if you can put the word *word* there without an article in front of *Latin*.

Comment: Seriously, what is the problem with the word "that" that you changed it into "which"?

Comment: I feel that the relative clause there should be non-restrictive (which means we should use *which* rather than *that*); we've already told the reader that the word is "lumbus," not any other word, so the information (i.e. the meaning of the word) is only supplementary. I could be wrong, though. That's why I'm not confident enough to write an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **word** is optional. Using **the** is not. If you don't use **word**, then you use **Latin** as an adjective to describe **"lumbus"**.

**That** versus **which** is slightly more complicated. As originally posted, with **that**, it is easily comprehensible but doesn't sound quite right. As Fantasier pointed out, that's because we already know which word it is.

Hence your sentence should read:

> The word “lumbar” came from the Latin word “lumbus”, which means "loin".

But you could alternatively say any of the following:

> The word “lumbar” came from the Latin “lumbus”, which means "loin".
>
> The word “lumbar” came from the Latin word that means "loin": "lumbus".
>
> The word “lumbar” came from the Latin “lumbus”, meaning "loin".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the style. Since the context is *clear* as you are talking about the origin of the word already mentioned, it is *understood* that you are talking about Latin word. So, *without the word 'word'*, it's *understandable*.

On the other hand, putting the word 'word' won't harm. In fact, you are staying more clear as there, 'Latin' serves as an adjective and you are just telling that you are talking about Latin word and not Latin language/culture or whatever.